# What are these antenna-like protrusions for on an airliner?

Tags: airliner, feature-identification

This is a JetBlue A320:

[image: JetBlue A320 with items on fuselage top/bottom indicated]

I've always wondered what these are for, but could never find the answer. I'm guessing a few of them are for receiving information from satellites.

Comment: Labeled them in numbers so you can describe what each one of them is for. Yeah I finally figured out how to get images from google drawings onto my question :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They are the various communication and navigation antennas of the aircraft. This figure shows the location of antennas in A320, the type of aircraft in picture.

[image: A320 antenna location]

Source: pprune.org

Some antenna (the ones with *) are optional and the installation varies with customer. The communication antenna location in A320 can be seen in this image.

[image: Comm antenna]

Image from airbus training course from airbus.altervista.org

And the navigation antenna location in this one:

[image: Nav antenna]

Image from airbus training course from airbus.altervista.org

The dome (2 in the picture) is the radome for the [wi-fi system introduced by Jetblue](http://www.nycaviation.com/2013/09/a320-finally-certified-for-livetvs-wi-fi-coming-soon-to-jetblue/), dubbed Fly-Fi.

[image: Wi Fi radome]

Source: nycaviation.com

So,

- 1,3,4 - VHF
- 2 - Wifi
- 6 - ELT

Comment: Actually 2 is probably the DirectTV antenna... maybe coupled with Wi-Fi

Comment: @slookabill Maybe. It has WiFi allright. See the [vox article on this](http://www.vox.com/2015/4/7/8361503/in-flight-wifi)

Comment: Why call it Fly-Wi when they could have easily called it Wi-Fly...

Comment: @immibis Apparently it is called Fly-Fi. Sorry for the mistake, though I'm in no position to answer why they came up with that name :)

Comment: Just a guess, but Wi-Fly might already be trademarked by a competitor.

Comment: @DanHulme - wi-fly is full of connotations negative for the bottom line. Rejected by marketing.

Comment: "Wi-fly? Because now there's Fly-Fi, your Fly-Wi solution for WiFi while you fly."

Comment: @ToddWilcox, don't give up your day job for a marketing career ;)

Comment: looooooooooooooooooooooool

Comment: I find it interesting that they list TCAS and GPS as optional...

Comment: How much drag (and, consequently, extra fuel consumption and emissions) does the Fly-Fi add?

Comment: @reirab: Along with the HF, ELT, and SATCOM antennae.

Comment: @sampablokuper Please ask that as a [new question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) rather than asking in the comments.

Comment: @Sean The ELT being optional is for MH.

Comment: @reirab: MH?  Malaysia Airlines?