# What are the circles/holes ahead of the wing of an MD-82?

Tags: feature-identification

In the picture below I noticed there are three circles or holes of some kind ahead of the wing, what are those?

[image]
([airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Meridiana/McDonnell-Douglas-MD-82-DC-9-82/2251771))

Comment: I totally want I-SMEL in my logbook.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The three large circles indicated in the question are [static port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot-static_system) plates. These measure the [static pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_pressure) of the surrounding air, which is used to measure airspeed and [altitude](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14789/1696).

[image: MD-80 Decal set with static ports labeled]

<sup>[Original Source](http://www.internetmodeler.com/2000/december/new-releases/drawdecal_md80windows.htm)</sup>

Thanks to [a link](http://www.hilmerby.com/photo/md80/photom8.html) from Jonathan Walters, here is a closeup of one:

[image: Static port closeup]

The four smaller areas in a row along the centerline are the [radar altimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_altimeter) transmitters/receivers. The radar altimeter uses radio waves to determine the aircraft's altitude above the ground. This diagram for the A345 has them further aft, they're in similar configurations on [other aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/21514/1696).

[image: A345 antenna locations with radar altimeters circled]

<sup>[Original Source](http://www.pprune.org/rumours-news/418896-bad-rwy-jfk-again-3.html)</sup>