# Is there any kind of removable ELT on board an airliner?

Tags: safety, airliner, equipment

Is there any equipment similar to an ELT on board on airline airplanes as for GA aircraft? Something that can be removed from the wreck in the event of abandoning the site of the crash.

Comment: I know that there is the Flight Data Recorder that keeps giving signal to rescue teams, but in case that the wreck must be abandoned how could I be sure to be found?

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate (you decide): [How is the emergency locator transmitter of the A320 fixed, activated and carried away?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43880/3201)

Comment: I don't believe that general aviation ELTs are designed to be easily removable in the event of a crash.

Comment: @Steve Kuo for what I know the ELT is removable, in the aircarft that I fly (cessna 152/172) is positioned in a case inside the fuselage on left side, the screws for that case are made of plastic which make them easier to brake if they get stuck due to impact. But I have never tried to open so far.

Comment: @mins thank's for reply. Good stuff. I appreciate.

Comment: What do you mean by removable? Every ELT is removable to some degree, depending on means of installation. All ELTs that I have worked on could be removed with means requiring minor mechanical skill and bare hands or simple tools.

Comment: If you are worried about being located in case of a crash, buy yourself a handheld EPIRB. They can be brought with you on carry-on luggage and cost as little as $125 on eBay.