# What is this little strake on Cessna 182 vertical tail?

Tags: aerodynamics, feature-identification, tail, cessna-182

What is the reason of mounting this little horizontal strake on a Cessna 182 vertical tail?[image]

Comment: All the irrelevant things I notice: A) why didn't they move their logo just a little forward on the tail so it doesn't run into the vortex generators? B) Why is there a car and a motor home parked in the hangar? C) Who has a garage on their house big enough to hold a 182 and a car and a motor home???

Comment: @FreeMan Re. B and C, can we assume you don't live in the US? :)

Comment: It is a VOR antenna. See also: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/67237/8749, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50120/8749, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38218/8749

Comment: Au contraire, @Pondlife, I do. I've seen garages for motor homes, but I don't know that I've ever seen one attached to a house that was large enough to hanger a small aircraft. Also, since IANAP, is parking road vehicles inside the hangar a "normal" thing? (I suppose if it's a private hangar you can park whatever you want in there...)

Comment: I didn't even thought about that. Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67237/what-is-this-flat-plate-sticking-out-of-the-tail-of-learjet-24d? ?  At least the answer is the same--

Comment: @FreeMan Google "airpark communities" for a sense of what's out there. It's pretty common to keep road vehicles, boats etc. in privately owned hangars. Airports usually have an "aviation use only" clause in hangar rental contacts but they're often ignored.

Comment: @FreeMan Believe it or not: in Germany we have a _garage regulation_ that only allows for storing items in a garage which are related to the car (and of course, a car itself). You may store winter tyres or a roof box but not a lawn mower or an old couch. :-) On the other hand, there's a German idiom which translates to _"no plaintiff, no judge."_ Dunno if that is known/common in English.

Comment: @PerlDuck Based on the stereotypes about Germans being neat, tidy, organized, and punctual I would absolutely believe that! Of course, stereotypes are _based_ in fact, even if they become extremely exaggerated... :)

Comment: @PerlDuck Our version is "it's only illegal if you get caught." In this case, as long as you actually have a plane in the hangar, airport authorities generally don't care what *else* you have in there. It's quite common to drive to your hangar and leave your car inside while you fly. They just want to stop folks from using them solely as storage units (or living space).

Comment: @FreeMan This is obviously a hangar, not a garage. Some people build their house (apartment) in their hanger :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's one half of a [VOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHF_omnidirectional_range) receiver antenna. There will be a corresponding element on the otherside of the tail.

The complete unit looks like this:

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://www.sensorantennas.com/product/vorlocglide-slope-antenna-4/)</sup>

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the the company from whom I borrowed the image - it was just a good image to illustrate the point.