# What is the purpose of the small vertical dorsal fin about halfway along the fuselage of the Boeing 737?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics

I've searched for an answer to this question on this site and others:

What is the purpose of the small vertical dorsal fin about halfway along the fuselage of the Boeing 737?

See the attached image where I have included an arrow pointing to the small fin.[image]

Comment: See [What are these antenna-like protrusions for on an airliner?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21513/14897)

Answer (score 2):

It's the antenna for the Left VHF communications radio - the ones for the Centre and Right radios can be seen under the fuselage.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I have long wondered what they were (I once thought they might have served an aerodynamic efficiency purpose similar to the strakes seen on engine cowlings).

Comment: Comms info on the 737...  scroll down for a diagram of the antennae placements on the fuselage.
http://www.b737.org.uk/communications.htm